# Set padding/margin for overflow table

Tags: css

I have a table that lives inside a div. That table has a huge content in it that overlap the window, so I need to scroll far to the left to see its content. Problem is that the table doesn't have a padding or margin on the right to make it more easier to read.

How can I add padding or margin to that table?

Here is the html looks like (Note that the css below doesn't work):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="table">
    <table>
        <thead>...</thead>
        <tbody>...</tbody>
    </table>  
</div>
<style>
table td, table th, table td {border: 1px solid red}
table { padding-right: 100px; border: 1px solid blue}
table thead, table tbody {padding-right: 100px;}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: place css in head section.. or in .css file and create link in head tag

Comment: Sure, this is just for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank for your answer.
However I see that doing it by via javascript is much easier and also very flexible. Here, I'm doing using jQuery framework:

```
 $('#table').width() = $('table').width() + 20;
 $('table').css('padding-right', '10px');
```

That will make the table width as it first intended to be.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this?

```
<style type="text/css">
      #table table td,#table table th,#table table td {border: 1px solid red}
      #table table { padding-right: 100px;color: blue}
      #table table thead,#table table tbody {padding-right: 100px;}
</style>
```

Comment: HI midstack, Thank you for your answer. Your solution seems to work at first. However, when I apply style to the table (by adding border to it). It doesn't function as I intend to do. Could you review your answer? Thank you.

Comment: Can you write it as    
   #table table, #table table td, #table table th{border: 1px solid #F00;}
      #table table { padding-right: 100px; color:#00F;}
      #table table thead,#table table tbody {padding-right: 100px;}
   I have tried and work fine but you must change padding as margin to make it look good

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: inline-block;` to the table

Answer (score 0):

In css, you dont need to prefix of . or # to table,td,tr,p,

in your issue, add following code

```
    #table table thead, table tbody {padding-right: 100px;}
```

Note # here... Because # is Id selector.

Good Luck ..!